# How do I add the product ID/SKU to my search results?

Tags: sku

I want to show the SKU code on search result listing page. 
Like this 
https://support.3dcart.com/knowledgebase/article/View/269/6/how-do-i-add-the-product-idsku-to-my-search-results
[image]
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hello Alex, welcome to Magento SE. What did you try so far? Show us the relevant codes

Answer (score 2):

In default Magento, the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` is responsible for listing searching products as in category pages. The template file assoicated with this is `catalog/product/list.phtml`.

So basically you need to set a new template to this block. This is because the default template is using in various places in Magento and hence if you apply the changes in that file directly, it is going to view in every place. So replace this template with another template. This is how you can achieve this via layout update XML.

File : `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>custom/catalog/product.list.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

Now copy paste the file in `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template/catalog/product/list.phtml` to `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template/custom/catalog/product/list.phtml`

In that file, you can see a `foreach` loop. put this code inside that loop in the exact place where you need to show your sku

```
<p><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?></p>
```